# NPM return “bash command not found” when I try to get a package version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I have installed the package.json that includes nodemon package (and others)

#npm list --depth 0

├─┬ nodemon@2.0.7

but the command #nodemon -v return a -bash error: "nodemon command not found”

I cant start my server.js with nodemon, the same error, but all works with #node server.js

Any idea? Thnks

Comment: You haven't installed nodemon globally so you need to use the path where it's deployed, something like `node_modules/cmd/nodemon`.

Comment: Or `npx nodemon`. This will search for the command in the current project, in global scope and online (in this order). In a Bash-like shell you can call the command with `$(npm bin)/nodemon` but I wasn't able to do this on Windows shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With a local install

You can use `npx nodemon filename.js`

### If you want to install it globally

With npm `npm install nodemon -g` or with yarn `yarn global add nodemon`, that way you can use `nodemon` directly (`nodemon filename.js`)